# Reading custom data format into Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet, filereader

I have a file of extension *.qub that I would like to read into Excel. The file contains spacecraft instrument data. The file has two parts, a SFDU-defined text header followed by binary data.

Ideally, we would like the user to be able to access the files using Excel's built-in File-->Open and File-->Save functionality to import/export this *.qub format.

What is the best way to create a custom file reader/writer in Excel?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://public.ccsds.org/publications/archive/621x0g1.pdf ?  Looks non-trivial ;-)

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams - Yes. Thats the format, but its not too bad when implemented. The header file is text and for the most part has key/value(s) sets. There are libraries written in C to parse the headers but I am not sure about how to call these existing libraries from excel...that's the next question. The headers look like this:         `/* File Structure */^M
^M
RECORD_TYPE = FIXED_LENGTH^M
RECORD_BYTES = 512^M
FILE_RECORDS =       5985^M
LABEL_RECORDS =         21^M
FILE_STATE = CLEAN^M`  The data is available to the public on NASA's Planetary Data System.